# What's the fastest way to check whether large arrays are identical in python?

Tags: python, hash, bigdata

I'm working with large datasets that take two forms.

1. A set of .tiff files (i.e. roughly 2000 files of 2048 x 2048 .tiff images)
2. An enormous hdf5 file which contains a ~2000x2048x2048 array.

I'm writing code that will take all the .tiff files and re-write them as a hdf5 file to make uploading and downloading easier, but I'd like to be able to write something to check if a hdf5 file is already present and if it is, to check whether that hdf5 file has the 2000x2048x2048 array and if it does, whether the data contained in that array is identical to the 2000 .tiff files.

The first two steps (check for hdf5 file and whether it has a huge array in it) are simple enough. But what's fastest reasonable way to do the last bit (see if the data are identical) in python? Ideally, I'd like something that doesn't take as long to check as it would take to just make another redundant hdf5 file.

Comment: You can certainly use an MD5 or SHA256 checksum to do this, but you'll need to plan it.  You could use a checksum of the TIFF files before converting to HDF5, but if you have any existing HDF5 files, you'd need to extract and checksum.  Is HDF5 really any easier than using a zip file?

Comment: hashing two files and then comparing the hashes is slower than just comparing the two files byte-for-byte. If you were comparing something to *the same* file multiple times, hashing might speed things up significantly. It's unclear to me how often your are performing these steps.